# Compile error: Expected identifier for UBound(array)

Tags: excel, vba

I'm an VBA newbie trying to use arrays and ran into the compile error: Expected Identifier when I simply tried to do the following.

```
Dim ExcludeDays() As Date
ubound(ExcludeDays) = Range("Exclude").End(xlDown).Row - Range("Exclude").Row
```

I've added all the common reference libraries but cannot get this to work. Any idea what may be happening here?

Thanks!

Comment: ubound gives the upper size of the array, it doesn't set it (read only). as Gary's Student showed, use Redim

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Right idea, just fix the syntax:

```
Dim ExcludeDays() As Date
ReDim ExcludeDays(1 to  Range("Exclude").End(xlDown).Row - Range("Exclude").Row)
```

Comment: Good to see the lower bound included, so +1 for that.  But given the context it probably should be `0`